# Real Analysis Set Theory Related Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have no idea what this set would be $$-A = \{ t \in \mathbb{R}: -t \in A \}$$. I'm thinking that it means it's all negative real numbers in the set $-A$. Furthermore, I don't know what $A$ would be.

Comment: It's simply the negatives of everything in $A.$

Comment: Let's say $A$ is a finite set of real numbers, some negative some positive. Then -A is the negative of every element in A, meaning this would flip the positive numbers in A to negative numbers, and negative numbers in A to positive numbers, right?

Comment: @snell_express: Yes, that's correct. For example, if $A=\{-2,3,4\}$ then $-A=\{2,-3,-4\}$.

Comment: A more natural (but equivalent) way to define $-A$ is: $-A = \{ -t\mid t \in A \}.$ It is the [image of the subset $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_a_subset) by the map $x\mapsto -x.$